# Image moves on hover when apply an opacity and transform

Tags: html, css

I have applied an effect to the image and when I hover over it it moves very strange, it is a move very small but I don't like it, also the text over the image moves when the mouse is out from the image.

This is my code, as you can see is a very imperceptible, but looks strange.
I also would like to make the images responsive when I change resolution, but I would like to have a height like 150px and make the image centered or crop it to the height.

This is my pen code: http://codepen.io/yunielth/pen/wWRydp

**HTML**

```
<div class="picture-block margin-0">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  sub-box-picture">
      <div class="content-inner">
         <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a title="" href="/cursos/madrid"><img src="http://charitywp.thimpress.com/demo-4/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/01_home_01_13-370x270.jpg"" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <a class="ciudades" title="" href="">Product 1</a><a href="" class="thim-button style3">See more</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  sub-box-picture">
      <div class="content-inner">
         <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://charitywp.thimpress.com/demo-4/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/01_home_01_13-370x270.jpg"" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <a class="ciudades" title="" href="">Product 2</a><a href="" class="thim-button style3">See more</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 hidden-xs sub-box-picture">
      <div class="content-inner">
         <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://charitywp.thimpress.com/demo-4/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/01_home_01_13-370x270.jpg"" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <a class="ciudades" title="" href="">Product 3</a><a href="" class="thim-button style3">See more</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 hidden-xs sub-box-picture">
      <div class="content-inner">
         <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://charitywp.thimpress.com/demo-4/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/01_home_01_13-370x270.jpg"" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <a class="ciudades" title="" href="">Product 4</a><a href="" class="thim-button style3">See more</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ciudades{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px #333;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90%;
}
.sub-box-picture .content-inner {
    border: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.sub-box-picture .entry-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-box-picture .entry-thumbnail .thumbnail::before {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: 2;
}


.sub-box-picture .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.sub-box-picture .thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all all 1s ease;
    transition: all all 1s ease;
}

.sub-box-picture .thumbnail {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.sub-box-picture .ciudades {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.thim-button.style3 {
    display: none;
}

.sub-box-picture a.ciudades {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.sub-box-picture:hover .entry-thumbnail .thumbnail::before {
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    -khtml-opacity: .5;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    opacity: .5;
    -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.thim-button.style3 {
    display: block;
}

.sub-box-picture:hover .thumbnail img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
    backface-visibility:     hidden;
}

.sub-box-picture .thim-button.style3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 3;
}

.sub-box-picture:hover .thim-button.style3 {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
}

.sub-box-picture:hover .ciudades {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
}



.thim-button.style3 {
    background-color: #3080B2;
    border-color: #3080B2;
    color: #fff;
}

.thim-button.style3:hover {
    background-color: #3080B2;
    border-color: #3080B2;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.thim-button {
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle, or at least format your code.

Comment: yes I have a pencode: http://codepen.io/yunielth/pen/wWRydp

Comment: Yes I see that. But the growing of the image is part of the code. You can just remove the transform if you don't want it to grow. Do you want a code snippet ?

Comment: Yes I want the image growth when hover, but I dont want the image to see blur and when the mouse out the text jump, if you know what I mean.